# Data-Grid sorting Logic

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, logic

```
private void buttonCD_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (MusicStoreEntities mr = new MusicStoreEntities())
    {
        dataGridChoice.ItemsSource = mr.ViewOfCD.ToList();
    }
    dataGridChoice.Columns[0].Header = "Genre";
    dataGridChoice.Columns[1].Header = "Musician";
    dataGridChoice.Columns[2].Header = "Album";
    dataGridChoice.Columns[3].Header = "Price";
}
```

Okay, so this is how I fill my data-grid. I have 2 more buttons like this for vinyl and cassette.

I did it like this because when I used `DisplayMemberPath`, I got a mix of rows, from chosen table (CD) and Genre, and it's just a mess!

I also have a button erase, for when I select an item from the data grid, it should be erased, first question is how does the app know from which SQL table the remove the item? The second question comes with the first, because I cannot use

```
CD c = (CD) datagrid.SelectedItem;
```

it gives me an exception, because I used a view for the data-grid!

any advice?

Comment: App wont know automatically, you have to take care of that. How you are fetching and binding data to dgrid.

Comment: Can i do it with if method? something like if(buttonCD.IsInitialized)?
i still have a problem with casting afterwards, because i used View or if I use Select method also, i cannot cast it into CD i don't know any way around it, and cannot find it online

Comment: Are you using LinqToSql or anything else ?

Comment: No, i'm using entity framework!

Comment: u must be knowing how to propagate changes to DB

Comment: i just found out the main problem, I can come up with a solution for the exception that is bugging me, but when I do, my datagrid looks awful.
to be more precise, my CD table has the Genre foreign key, cause i sort them according to the Genre, right.
So that being said, when i Call upon my ShowCD(); with out the Select(), it just scrambles my Data-grid, showing cdID, GenreID not showing the name of the genre etc. it is just a mess, and if i do it this way, i dont know how to make the data-grid show just what i want!